# Creating multiple path distance outputs using ModelBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.2, modelbuilder

I am trying to create a model in ArcMap that will run a path distance analysis on each individual polygon in a feature class.

Below is the model I have so far but it is only outputting one path distance rather than an individual one for each of the polygons in my feature class.

I have selected 'Id' as the field in the Iterator (each polygon has a different ID number'. The output from the iterator is my input feature in my path distance tool and then the 'ReCamp2' is my input cost raster.

Do I need another tool to get my path distance to save the results from each polygon separately?

[image]

Comment: Does the input layer into the iterator have a section on it (i.e. does it have 1 polygon selected)? If so make sure you have cleared that selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try adding the [Rename Tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000056000000) to the right of your output raster(s).  As your input to the Rename Tool, connect your output raster(s).  For the output data parameter in the Rename Tool, you should input the file name you desire.  In your case, something to the effect of "C:\temp\HogHab1_%Value%" or "C:\temp\ModRas1_%Value%" respectively.  What the %Value% does is fetch the id value.  Try that and let us know.